# Discord channel members only returns one member?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am running a bot on a test server. There are currently three members in the channel (member_count of 3), but it only returns one member. This member is the Bot.

The code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = "<Token>"
CHANNEL_ID = 1234

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    print(channel.members)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Output:

```
[<Member id=<> name='Bot_name' discriminator='Bot_discriminator' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=<> name="Server_name" shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=3>>]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py- guild.members and ctx.guild.members not working, but only on certain computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64191447/discord-py-guild-members-and-ctx-guild-members-not-working-but-only-on-certain)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Discord recently changed their bot api, which may be responsible for what you're seeing.

The good news is that the fix is reasonably easy, you just need to enable the "Server Members Intent" in your bot's admin page. Follow [the instructions here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents).

Answer (score 4):

###### After enabling the GUILD_MEBERS intent.

The list members API endpoint has a default limitation of 1 for the number of result.
If you're making HTTP requests instead of using discord.js SDK, you have to add a 'limit' query param.

so `https://discord.com/api/guilds/<guild-id>/members` becomes `https://discord.com/api/guilds/<guild-id>/members?limit=1000`

https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#list-guild-members

Comment: crazy how this was the solution to the problem. I wonder why they didn't just set a reasonable default for the limit

Answer (score 0):

Try to looping through the channel.members
**For example:**

```
for i in channel.members:
 print(i.id)
```

Comment: Hi! That also only returns the ID of my bot.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it into a command which will get the count of members in the channel the command used in.

Docs:

- [TextChannel.members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel%20members#discord.TextChannel.members)
- [Member.name](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member%20name#discord.Member.name)

```py
@bot.command()
async def count(ctx):
    print(len(ctx.channel.members)) # to show how many are there
    for member in ctx.channel.members:
        print(member.name)
```